# Need to output prefix based on last letter of a noun

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment with an online Udacity course, where we have been asked to develop a method that recognizes the last letter of the noun and then based on the letter, out put a "La", "el", or "?" + the noun.

The complete instructions are You are to complete the method fixNoun in the SpanishWord class so that it returns the noun preceded by:

```
// "la " if the noun ends in "a",
// "el " if it ends in "o"
// "? " if it ends in some other letter.
```

I seem to keep getting all failures when compiling. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
public String fixNoun(String noun) {
    String determinenet= noun.substring(noun.length() - 1);      

    if(determinenet.equals("a")) {
       System.out.println("la" + " "+noun );
    }
    else if ( determinenet.equals("o")) {
       System.out.println( "el"+ " "+noun);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("?"+ " "+noun);
    }

    return noun;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire class ?

Comment: What failures do you get. Please post the output you get when trying to compile your class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't return the altered noun but the old one. In your code you have to change the

```
System.out.println("la" + " "+noun );
```

to

```
return("la " + noun);
```

and so on.

The fixed code looks like this:

```
public String fixNoun(String noun) { 
    String determinenet= noun.substring(noun.length() - 1);

       if(determinenet.equals("a")) {
          return("la" + " "+noun );
       }
       else if ( determinenet.equals("o")) {
          return( "el"+ " "+noun);
       }
       else {
           return("?"+ " "+noun);
       }
    } 
}
```

P.S.: The String class has a method endsWith() that gives you the last character of the string.

So you also could write your code like this:

```
public String fixNoun(String noun) {
    if(noun.endsWith("a")) {
        return("la " + noun);
    else if(noun.endsWith("o")) {
        return("el " + noun);
    else {
        return("? " + noun);
    }
}
```

Good luck with your assignment :)

Comment: Glad this was of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know maybe i'm wrong. how about this?

```
String de=noun.charAt(noun.length()-1)
if(de.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
    return "la" + " "+noun ;
```